# How can I ssh into my Cloud9 workspace?

Tags: linux, ssh, aws-cloud9

I want to ssh into my Cloud9 workspace. I have set the default "ubuntu" user's password using `sudo passwd ubuntu`, although this gets reset every time I reload the IDE.  I found the workspace's IP using `curl ipecho.net/plain` and then scanned it with nmap and found that port 22 is open. It is hosted by Google Cloud, and changes whenever I reload the IDE. When I try to connect over ssh, my connection times out. The ssh terminal in Cloud9 is connected to a treasure data website over https.  When I scan the treasure IP, ssh is not open. I think it is being tunneled or something.  Doing `sudo lsof -i`, I learned that the workspace is running dropbear on port 58777 on some local IP, but I don't think this affects ssh'ing from the outside.

So there is the Google Cloud IP with ssh open, but to which I cannot ssh, the treasure data IP which is probably tunneled, and a few Cloud9 local IPs which I can't connect to anyway. How can I ssh into my Cloud9 workspace?

Comment: https://c9.io/support

Comment: Cloud 9 talks a lot about how you can ssh from the cloud 9 ide into your own server, but not how you can do the reverse, which is what I am interested in.  I'm not sure if it is officially supported yet.

Comment: I linked you to their support. Ask them.

Comment: I am also interested in this, have you found a solution?

Comment: This is possible on the new AWS Cloud 9 since is uses AWS EC2 instances for the workspace.  Within Cloud 9 you have full root access to an EC2 linux server which you can configure to allow outside ssh access.

Answer (score 9):

The network traffic can be simply redirected using tunnelling, however cloud9 sshd does not allow to log in using password, and the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file is protected.

You can bypass this, by setting up your own `dropbear` on cloud9. I have done it like this:

```
wget https://matt.ucc.asn.au/dropbear/dropbear-2015.67.tar.bz2
tar xjf dropbear-2015.67.tar.bz2
cd dropbear-2015.67
./configure --prefix /home/ubuntu/workspace
```

added the following line:

```
#define DEBUG_HACKCRYPT "hL8nrFDt0aJ3E" /* this is crypt("password") */
```

to `options.h`, then:

```
make
make install
```

Then I have run `dropbear` on port 2222:

```
cd /home/ubuntu/workspace
bin/dropbearkey -t rsa -f dropbear_rsa_host_key
sbin/dropbear -E -F -p 2222 -r dropbear_rsa_host_key
```

On another cloud9 terminal I have tunelled the port 2222 to some.server:

```
ssh user@some.server -R 2222:localhost:2222
```

After doing this I was able to login from some.server:

```
ssh -p 2222 ubuntu@localhost
```

using password "password".

Comment: What is some.server? Why is C9 connecting to it?

Comment: some.server is a computer with ssh that is accessible from internet, and we have an account on it